# Localisation of comma separated dynamic variables which are react elements

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Hi in our project we are using "react-i18-next" for localisation. I came across a use case where i have to construct a comma separated dynamic error messages for eg.

1. A and B are required.
2. A, B and C are required.
3. A, B, C and D are required.

where A, B & C will a react node itself.

Here it is impossible to form all the cases. So the solution which i can think of is

1. list of comma separated variables together
2. keeping "and" with and last label with static text

```
<Trans>
{upfrontLabels} and {lastLabel} are required
</Trans>
```

But issue with the above solution is that in different languages we don't have comma for eg in French we use ; and in Arabic we use Arabic comma.

I read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/ListFormat but i didn't see how it can be integrated with react-18-next